# Google text- to-Speech gTTs not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, gtts

I installed gtts using "pip3 install gTTs", but I am getting this error whenever I run the program.

> from gtts import gTTs.
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'gTTs'

This is the part of the code which is generating the error.I am using speak() as a module.

```
from os import system
from gtts import gTTs



def speak(text):
   tts = gTTS(text,lang = 'en')
   tts.save("speech.mp3")
   system("mpg321 speech.mp3")
```

I checked whether gtts is installed or not using "pip3 freeze" and it shows gtts amongst the packages

Comment: There's a type missing - `import gTTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `from gtts import gTTs` with `from gtts import gTTS`